# Some RAM sticks cause POST fail

Tags: windows, boot, memory, cpu, motherboard

I've got a weird one for you guys. I'm wondering if my problem is with my motherboard or my RAM, or both.

I have 4 sticks of DDR3 RAM. Two 4GB, and two 8GB. All 4 used to work until my PC crashed one day and kept performing repeated restarts immediately after booting. No boot screen or anything, just rolling restarts with black screen (no signal on monitor).

I mixed and matched each stick on different slots until it booted. It started booting with 4GB on slot 1, and 4GB on slot 3 (dual channel). Adding either of the 8GB sticks to this mix either causes the rolling restarts again, or a simple failure to POST (PC turns on but no signal on monitor).

Here's the kicker: if I change the positions of the working sticks to other slots, it'll either work, or not work. It seems random. Even putting the sticks back into slots 1 and 3 will sometimes cause POST failure.

The 8GB sticks don't seem to work in any configuration.

My gut tells me it's a motherboard issue but I'm not sure. I guess it could be the CPU, too.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You must install memory modules in the correct configuration as documented by your motherboard manufacture.  You cannot simply use any configuration you want.  However, if the 4 GB modules work in the proper configuration, and the 8 GB modules never work then it's a problem with the 8 GB modules.

Answer (score 1):

No reason that a configuration that used to work no longer works after a crash,
unless the crash caused damage to some RAM sticks or their motherboard slots.
It sounds like one or more 8GB sticks got fried, but testing is required.

Insert the sticks one-by-one (if the motherboard can work with only one),
to find if one or more sticks is faulty. If they are all good, then
something is wrong with the motherboard.

Any more in-depth testing would require a professional repair-shop.

If the catastrophic crash was caused by an electrical spike, it is important
in the future to protect the computer with at least a surge protector.

Comment: Right, so the issue with the one-by-one test is that even the slots that are currently working with the 4GB sticks may not work again if the sticks are removed and reinserted, even if it's just one stick at a time in slot 1. It's unreliable - seems to only work when it wants to. Would you recommend I try to take the sticks to a repair place to see if they're fried?

Comment: I would take the computer *and* the sticks.